# C# Blazor test form with bUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, blazor, xunit

I have a `Blazor` page and want to do unittesting via `bUnit` with `xUnit`.

My `Blazor`-page:

```
<EditForm Model="login" OnValidSubmit="@LoginSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <p>
        <MatBlazor.MatTextField @bind-Value="@login.Mail" Label="Mail-Address" Icon="mail_outline" Dense="true"></MatBlazor.MatTextField>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => login.Mail)" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <MatBlazor.MatTextField @bind-Value="@login.Password" Label="Password" Icon="lock_outline" Type="password"></MatBlazor.MatTextField>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => login.Password)" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <MatBlazor.MatButton Label="Login" Type="Submit" Raised="true"></MatBlazor.MatButton>
        <MatBlazor.MatButton Label="Register" @onclick="NavigateRegister" Outlined="true"></MatBlazor.MatButton>
    </p>
</EditForm>
```

and my UnitTest:

```
var ctx = MyTestContext();
var cut = ctx.RenderComponent<Login>();

var inputs = cut.FindAll("input");
var input1 = inputs.Where(x => x.ParentElement.TextContent.Contains("Mail")).FirstOrDefault();
input1.Change(testuser);
var input2 = inputs.Where(x => x.ParentElement.TextContent.Contains("Password")).FirstOrDefault();
input2.Change("s3cur3_PASS");
var buttons = cut.FindAll("button");
var button = buttons.Where(x => x.TextContent.Contains("Login")).FirstOrDefault();
button.Click();
```

However the function `LoginSubmit` is never triggered.
Even when I search for `form` instead of `buttom` and perform `Submit()` instead of `Click()`, the function `LoginSubmit` isn't triggered.

What can I do in order to

1. Trigger function `LoginSubmit`
2. Trigger the invalid states?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was that only the first `Change()` was recognized.
This is because after every change, submit and click the UI is rendered again.
It is smarter to call it the following way:

```
var ctx = MyTestContext();
var cut = ctx.RenderComponent<Login>();

cut.Find("input[aria-label=Mail-Address]").Change(testuser);
cut.Find("input[type=password]").Change("s3cur3_PASS");
cut.Find("form").Submit();
```