# Unit testing a Blazor form with MudBlazor controls using bUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, blazor, xunit, bunit

I'm following great documentation from [bUnit](https://bunit.dev/docs/getting-started/writing-tests.html?tabs=xunit), [MudBlazor](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/tree/dev/src/MudBlazor.UnitTests/Components) and an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64635986/8644294), but somehow my code is not behaving the way it should, so I should be making some silly mistake somewhere.

This is how my form page/ component (`NewRepairPage.razor`) looks like:

```
@page "/repairs/new"

<h3>New Repair Order</h3>

<EditForm Model="@NewROViewModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleFormSubmit">
    <FluentValidationValidator @ref="_fluentValidationValidator" />
    <MudGrid>
        <MudItem xs="12">
            <MudCard>
                <MudCardContent>
                    <MudGrid>
                        <MudItem xs="6">
                            <MudAutocomplete T="Unit" Label="Search by unit number..."
                                             ToStringFunc="@(e=> e==null?null : $"{e.UnitNumber} ({e.Make.Trim()})")"
                                             Value="NewROViewModel.Unit"
                                             SearchFunc="@GetUnitNumbers"
                                             ResetValueOnEmptyText="@true"
                                             CoerceText="@true"
                                             CoerceValue="@true"
                                             ValueChanged="OnUnitChanged"
                                             For="@(() => NewROViewModel.Unit)" />
                        </MudItem>
                        <MudItem xs="6">
                            <MudSelect @bind-Value="NewROViewModel.RepairLocation" Label="Repair Location" For="@(() => NewROViewModel.RepairLocation)">
                                @foreach (var repLocationSelectListItem in RepairLocations)
                                {
                                    <MudSelectItem Value="@repLocationSelectListItem.Value">@repLocationSelectListItem.Text</MudSelectItem>
                                }
                            </MudSelect>
                        </MudItem>
                    </MudGrid>        
                    <MudGrid>
                        <MudItem xs=6>
                            <MudDatePicker Label="Promised Date" @bind-Date="NewROViewModel.PromisedDatetime" For="@(() => NewROViewModel.PromisedDatetime)" ShowWeekNumbers="true" />
                        </MudItem>
                    </MudGrid>
                </MudCardContent>
                <MudCardActions>
                    <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto">Create Repair Order</MudButton>
                </MudCardActions>
            </MudCard>
        </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>
</EditForm>
```

The viewmodel looks like this:

```
public class RepairOrderViewModel
{
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }
    public string RepairLocation { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PromisedDatetime { get; set; }

    public class NewROValidator : AbstractValidator<RepairOrderViewModel>
    {
        public NewROValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(rovm => rovm.Unit).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Unit Number is required");
            RuleFor(rovm => rovm.RepairLocation).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Repair Location is required");
            RuleFor(rovm => rovm.PromisedDatetime).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Promised Date is required");
        }
    }
}
```

The code behind (`NewRepairPage.razor.cs`):

```
public partial class NewRepairPage : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IDbContextFactory<MMTDbContext> DbContextFactory { get; set; } = default!;

    [Inject]
    public IOptions<AppSettings> AppSettings { get; set; } = default!;

    [Inject]
    private ISnackbar Snackbar { get; set; } = default!;

    [Inject]
    public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; } = default!;

    public RepairOrderViewModel NewROViewModel { get; set; } = new RepairOrderViewModel();

    private List<SelectListItem> RepairLocations { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();

    FluentValidationValidator? _fluentValidationValidator;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        RepairLocations = await GetRepairLocations();
    }

    private async Task HandleFormSubmit()
    {
        var validationResult = _fluentValidationValidator?.Validate();
        if (validationResult.HasValue && validationResult.Value)
        {
            // Submit the form
            // Success:
            var orderIdJustCreated = 123;
            Snackbar.Add($"Repair order successfully created!", MudBlazor.Severity.Success);

            NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/repairorder/single/{orderIdJustCreated}");

            // Failure:
            // Handle appropriately
        }
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Unit>> GetUnitNumbers(string searchText)
    {
        using var db = await DbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
        return await db.Units.ToListAsync(); // Put filter here based on searchText
    }

    public async Task<List<SelectListItem>> GetRepairLocations()
    {
        // return List of new SelectListItem { Text = x.Descrip, Value = x.Code } from the database here
    }

    private void OnUnitChanged(TMTUnit value)
    {
        NewROViewModel.Unit = value;
        // Do other conditional stuffs here
    }
```

The test method:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Should_Be_Able_To_Submit_Form_SuccessfullyAsync()
{
    // --------------ARRANGE---------------------

    // Fake IOptions
    var fakeOptions = Options.Create(new AppSettings() { /* Set properties here */ }); // AppSettings is a class I created

    // Fake Db
    var mockDbFactory = new Mock<IDbContextFactory<MMTDbContext>>();
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MMTDbContext>()
                        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "DatabaseInMemory")
                        .Options;

    // Insert seed data into the database using one instance of the context
    using (var context = new MMTDbContext(options))
    {
        context.Units.Add(new Unit { UnitId = 1, UnitNumber = "11001", Make = "Honda ", Descrip = "My Test Unit" });
        context.Codes.Add(new Codes { CodeKey = "REPAIRSITE", Code = "CUST", Descrip = "CUSTOMER" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    // Now the in-memory db already has data, we don't have to seed everytime the factory returns the new DbContext:
    mockDbFactory.Setup(f => f.CreateDbContextAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(() => new MMTDbContext(options));

    // Fake NavigationManager
    // bUnit already comes with a fake navigation manager

    // Create BUnit test context
    using var ctx = new TestContext();

    // Now inject these fake services into the service container
    ctx.ComponentFactories.Add(() => Mock.Of<MudSelect<string>>());
    ctx.ComponentFactories.Add(Mock.Of<MudDatePicker>());
    ctx.ComponentFactories.Add(() => Mock.Of<MudPopover>());
            
    ctx.Services.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<ISnackbar>()); // Fake ISnackbar
    ctx.Services.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<IDialogService>()); // Do I even need it? I don't think I do but it throws exception if I don't add it here.
    ctx.Services.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<IScrollManager>()); // Do I even need it? I don't think I do but it throws exception if I don't add it here
    ctx.Services.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<IKeyInterceptorFactory>()); // Do I even need it? I don't think I do but it throws exception if I don't add it here
    ctx.Services.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<IBrowserWindowSizeProvider>()); // Do I even need it? I don't think I do but it throws exception if I don't add it here
    ctx.Services.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<IMudPopoverService>()); // Do I even need it? I don't think I do but it throws exception if I don't add it here
    ctx.Services.AddSingleton(mockDbFactory.Object);
    ctx.Services.AddSingleton(fakeOptions);

    var newRepairPage = ctx.RenderComponent<NewRepairPage>();

    // --------------SET VALUE IN THE FORM COMPONENTS---------------------
    
    // Set value in the autocomplete control
    var autocompletecomp = newRepairPage.FindComponent<MudAutocomplete<TMTUnit>>();
    var unit = new Unit { UnitId = 1, UnitNumber = "11001", Make = "Honda ", Descrip = "My Test Unit", Model = "Ashish", Status = "TipTop", Type = "Cool", Meters = new List<UnitMtr> { new UnitMtr { UMeterId = 1, MeterDefId = 1, LastReading = 100M } } };
    // This doesn't work. Is there a better way?
    await newRepairPage.InvokeAsync(() => newRepairPage.Find("div.mud-grid-item:nth-child(1) div.mud-autocomplete input.mud-input-slot").Change(unit));

    // Mudselect component
    // Find all MudSelect components
    var selectcomps = newRepairPage.FindComponents<MudSelect<string>>();

    // Find the desired MudSelect component based on its label
    var targetLabel1 = "Repair Location";
    var repLocationSelectComp = selectcomps.FirstOrDefault(comp => comp.Instance.Label == targetLabel1);
    // This doesn't work. Is there a better way?
    newRepairPage.Find("mud-item:nth-child(1) mud-select.mud-input-control select").Change("CUSTOMER");
    
    // Mudpicker component
    var datecomp = newRepairPage.FindComponent<MudDatePicker>();
    // This doesn't work. In fact this component is not even rendered in the 'newRepairPage'.
    // Is there a better way?
    newRepairPage.Find("mud-item:nth-child(1) mud-date-picker.mud-input-control input").Change(DateTime.Now);

    // --------------ACT---------------------
    // Submit the form
    newRepairPage.Find("form").Submit();

    // --------------ASSERT---------------------
    // Assert that the Snackbar has successful feedback and it navigates to the view order page, basically verify below 2 lines from the code behind of Razor component form
    //Snackbar.Add($"Repair order successfully created!", MudBlazor.Severity.Success);
    //NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/repairorder/single/{orderIdJustCreated}");
    // How do I verify this?
}
```

The issue with the test method is that I'm unable to set value in my components and hit submit.
One of the components isn't even rendered in the `newRepairPage` rendered component (datepicker control). So, I feel like I'm not doing this right.

Anyone have a better way of doing this? Also appreciate if someone could help with comment questions inside my test method.

Comment: Looking at your markup, it seems as if you are essentially only testing 3rd party components, either those from the Blazor framework or Mud. That is perhaps not a test you want, since it depends heavily on the implementation details of Mud, which may change without breaking the public behavior of the components you are using.

Instead, if you want to verify the correct data/parameters are being passed to the Mud components, you can mock/substitute them, and verify the expected parameters were passed to the substitutes. https://bunit.dev/docs/providing-input/substituting-components

Comment: @EgilHansen Thank you for the comment. I'm not testing the MudComponents, I'm just using them to input values in my form elements and test the behavior of my submit method when I submit the form.

Comment: @EgilHansen Can you please help in this case? I'm stuck. Basically, what I'm trying to do is render the form component by mocking the injected dependencies, set the input in the MudBlazor controls, do submit and test my submit method.

Comment: Mud uses bUnit extensively to test their own components, so my best suggestions is to look at how they are doing that on GitHub or substitute out the mud components, for that, see https://bunit.dev/docs/providing-input/substituting-components.html

Comment: @EgilHansen Thank you for that link. I used that to solve the errors in my test method. Now I've updated the test method and the question. If you could help with the new issues I'm having, that'd be great.

Comment: Having an ongoing dialog with a Stack Overflow member using updated code in your question isn't really how Stack Overflow works.  Maybe revert your post to the previous version of your question, and ask a new question with your new code?